# BETWEEN with datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I use PostgreSQL 8.4.11 and get a strange error. When I query:

```sql
SELECT "documents_document"."given_on" 
FROM "documents_document" 
WHERE (EXTRACT('month' FROM "documents_document"."given_on") = 1
       AND "documents_document"."given_on" 
       BETWEEN '1-01-01 00:00:00' and '1-12-31 23:59:59.999999') 
ORDER BY "documents_document"."created_on" DESC
```

I get results:

```
  given_on  
------------
 2002-01-16
 2011-01-25
 2012-01-12
 2012-01-12
 2012-01-12
 2012-01-20
 2012-01-19
 2012-01-13
 2012-01-31
 2012-01-16
 2012-01-31
 2012-01-12
 ...
```

Why?

I would expect dates in interval 1-01-01 ... 1-12-31.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You expected dates *"in interval 1-01-01 ... 1-12-31"*.
But how is PostgreSQL supposed to know what you mean by that?

Input string literals are interpreted according to the settings of your current session (which defaults to general settings in `postgressql.conf` unless overruled). In particular [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE):

> `DateStyle` (`string`)
>
> Sets the display format for date and time values, as well as the rules
> for interpreting ambiguous date input values. For historical reasons,
> this variable contains two independent components: the output format
> specification (`ISO`, `Postgres`, `SQL`, or `German`) and the
> input/output specification for year/month/day ordering (`DMY`, `MDY`,
> or `YMD`). These can be set separately or together. The keywords
> `Euro` and `European` are synonyms for `DMY`; the keywords `US`,
> `NonEuro`, and `NonEuropean` are synonyms for `MDY`. See [**Section
> 8.5**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) for more information. The built-in default is `ISO, MDY`, but initdb will initialize the configuration file with a setting that
> corresponds to the behavior of the chosen `lc_time` locale.

(While output format is mostly determined by [`lc_time`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-TIME).)

In your case, the mutilated timestamp literal `1-12-31 23:59:59` is obviously interpreted as:

```
D-MM-YY h24:mi:ss
```

While you would have hoped for:

```
Y-MM-DD h24:mi:ss
```

#### 3 options

1. Set `datestyle` so that it interprets literals in the same way as you do. Maybe `ISO, YMD`?
2. Use [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to interpret the string literal in a well defined way - independent of other settings. Much better.

   ```
    SELECT to_timestamp('1-12-31 23:59:59', 'Y-MM-DD h24:mi:ss');
   ```
3. Better yet, use **ISO 8601 format** (`YYYY-MM-DD`) for all datetime literals. That is [**unambiguous and independent from any settings**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE).

   ```
    SELECT '2001-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp;
   ```

#### Rewrite query

Your query is faulty to begin with. Handle range queries differently. Like:

```sql
SELECT d.given_on 
FROM   documents_document d
WHERE  EXTRACT('month' FROM d.given_on) = 1
AND    d.given_on >= '2001-01-01 0:0'
AND    d.given_on <  '2002-01-01 0:0'
ORDER  BY d.created_on DESC;
```

Or, simpler yet:

```sql
SELECT d.given_on 
FROM   documents_document d
WHERE  d.given_on >= '2001-01-01'
AND    d.given_on <  '2001-02-01'
ORDER  BY d.created_on DESC;
```

`'2001-02-01'` is perfectly valid timestamp input. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

[Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) in PostgreSQL 9.2 or newer may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for response! I think, i do third option in monday.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT '1-12-31 23:59:59.999999'::timestamp;` returns `2031-01-12 23:59:59.999999`, apparently Postgres does not consider year-without-century as first element in the date.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what format you wanted it in. So it gives back the native format. Perhaps you even assumed that everyone denotes time the way you do? 
Have a look at the possible formats. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html