# How to select in the query a time range of 1 hour?

Tags: database, postgresql

How to select in the query a time range of 1 hour?

**SQL**

```
select * from 
  history 
where
  clock == current_timestamp - interval '01:00:00'::timestamp;
```

**DATA WITH FUNCTION to_timestamp**

```
28689   2019-10-26 21:02:09 83.6353
28689   2019-10-26 21:01:39 83.6614
28689   2019-10-26 21:01:09 82.9015
28689   2019-10-26 21:00:39 82.9039
```

**OUTPUT**

> Invalid input syntax

The desired output is a select where the `clock` column that is a timestamp is within a one hour range of the values ​​that were entered.

Comment: Here is a previous answer which may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425853/postgresql-between-with-datetime

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I will take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try extracting the hour component from both your `clock` column and the current timestamp, and then comparing the difference between the two.

```
select *
from history 
where
    abs(extract(hour from clock) - extract(hour from current_timestamp)) <= 1;
```

If you instead want all records within the last hour, then try:

```
select *
from history
where extract(epoch from current_timestamp - clock) / 3600 <= 1;
```

Comment: Your first solution solved my problem, I just had to sort the CLOCK column down, thank you very much!