# Return number of days passed in current quarter

Tags: postgresql, date, date-math

How can I get the number of days passed in the current quarter?

For example, if today is 1/2/2021, it will return 2.
If today is 2/5, it will return 36.
If today is 4/2, it will return 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to get the start of the quarter and subtract dates:

```sql
WITH cte(day) AS (
   VALUES 
     (date '2021-01-02')
   , (date '2021-02-05')
   , (date '2021-04-02')
   )
SELECT day
     , day - date_trunc('quarter', day)::date + 1 AS days_passed_in_quarter
FROM   cte;

    day     | days_passed_in_quarter 
------------+------------------------
 2021-01-02 |                      2
 2021-02-05 |                     36
 2021-04-02 |                      2
```

`+ 1` to fix off-by-one error as you clearly want to *include* the current day as "passed".

Always use unambiguous ISO 8601 date format (`YYYY-MM-DD` - `2021-02-05`), which is the default in Postgres and always unambiguous, or you depend on the current [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting (and may be in for surprises). Also avoids misunderstandings general communication.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL: between with datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425853/postgresql-between-with-datetime/12426809#12426809)